# Correct Sample Space for Calculating P-Value

Tags: correlation, cross-validation, p-value, permutation-test, false-discovery-rate

Suppose there are two variables, *x* and *y*, and we wish to calculate some test statistic (say the Pearson correlation), and estimate its significance. The pvalue is calculated by estimating the probability that a random permutation of *x* will have a higher test statistic than the original one. The sample space is the permutations of indices, therefore.

A different way to calculate a pvalue, would use a different sample space. Say that we take a random subset of the rows, and calculate a linear prediction from *x* to *y* (which, of course, is closely related to the correlation). We could check if the prediction on the holdout data has a positive *r2* score. Repeating this for many random subsets, we could define the pvalue as the estimated probability that a linear prediction from *x* to *y*, would not be beneficial on holdout data. Here the sample space is the subsets of indices.

Is there a rule (or some intuition) for choosing the sample space for calculating the pvalue? Specificcally, suppose that the goal is predicting *y*, assessing the prediction through cross validated *r2*. Suppose further that the purpose of the pvalue is to decide (e.g., through the FDR), whether *x* is a good feature for predicting *y*. Since the natural sample space for cross-validation is a subset of the rows, then the pvalue of the features should be calculated through the same sample space, no?